# How to fetch data from a specific row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a small 3x4 table as shown in this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rat8e/29/)

Clicking the image gives an alert which basically has the entire row data of the image which was clicked.

However it doesn't work in any browser (in Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m, IE 10 and Firefox 25.0.1) . My code is shown below. *"jquery-1.9.1.js"* is actually [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) present in the same folder as that of the php file. Any clue why it isn't working outside JSFiddle? Also, will it work if I fetch the data from an Oracle database using `while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS))`?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
        $("img.print").click(function (event) {
            //Prevent the hyperlink to perform default behavior
            event.preventDefault();
            var $td = $(this).parent().closest('tr').children('td');
            var string1 = $td.eq(0).text();
            var string2 = $td.eq(1).text();
            var string3 = $td.eq(2).text();
            alert(string1+' '+string2+' '+string3);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
echo '
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12e4484b5ae3e5f676efb7c18cbac643?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG" class="print"></img></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12e4484b5ae3e5f676efb7c18cbac643?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG" class="print"></img></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>    
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12e4484b5ae3e5f676efb7c18cbac643?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG" class="print"></img></td>
    </tr>
</table>
';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copy pasting the exact code doesn't work. (in Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m, IE 10 and Firefox 25.0.1)

Comment: it's work for me on Chrome 32.0.1700.55 beta-m Aura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because the DOM is not built up yet at the time your code runs.

You should either put your `script` tags before the closing `body` tag (which is a good practice anyway) or only [run your code when the DOM is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("img.print").click(function (event) {
        //Prevent the hyperlink to perform default behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        var $td = $(this).parent().closest('tr').children('td');
        var string1 = $td.eq(0).text();
        var string2 = $td.eq(1).text();
        var string3 = $td.eq(2).text();
        alert(string1+' '+string2+' '+string3);
    });

});
```

Also, the way you are including jQuery is wrong. A `script` tag with an `src` should not have content. So you need two `script` tags:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script>
    $("img.print").click(function (event) {
        //...
    });
</script>
```

One more note: never forget to specify the DOCTYPE, it's very important!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Comment: @RajarshiSarkar Any errors in the Javascript console of your browser?

Comment: >> Your both methods doesn't work. No errors in Javascript console. Has to be something else.

Comment: Also, adding <!DOCTYPE html> doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes, I combined - "Put your script tags before the closing body tag" and "A script tag with an src should not have content"  and "never forget to specify the DOCTYPE"

Comment: @RajarshiSarkar My first two points (ready and script tags) are CERTAINLY problems with your code. The doctype should be added, to prevent other bad things happening. You need to combine all 3 things I mentioned and if it still does not work, elaborate more because these are the three main caveats I can see in the code you have posted.

Comment: @kapa>> Thanks, the problem was with DOM. It works fine now. Thanks a lot.